# Okhttp make thousands of client connections

Tags: performance, okhttp

is it possible to make thousands of WebSocket connections to a server like to do a load test? So far the most I have been able to make is 4000 using okhttp before I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create a native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is don't use okHttp ha.  I switched to using vertx http client and can open as many connections as I want doesn't even get my fan spinning.